# Using Storyboard to insert row in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitableview

I have 3 view controllers.

Navigation Controller - `N`

Table View Controller - `T`

Custom View Controller - `C`

Their layout is like so:

`N` -(root view controller)-> `T` -(bar button item Add - Triggered Segue)-> `C`

Just to clarify, `T` has an "Add" button which has a triggered segue action to present `C` modally.

`C` and `T` both have custom classes. `C` is a simple `UIViewController` subclass while `T` is a `UITableViewController` subclass.

In `T` I declare an `NSMutableArray` and a `UITableView` like so:

```
@interface T: UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *myTableData;
    IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
}
```

In `C` I have two elements within:

A `UITextField`

A `UIButton` called "send"

I connect the text field to an IBOutlet like so in `C`'s header, as well as create an action for the button:

```
@interface C: UITableViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *itemToAdd;
}
-(IBAction)addItem:(id)sender;
```

So I have the data array `myTableData` which populates `T`'s table declared and initialized in `T` (I will add a `myTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` in the `viewDidLoad` method of `T`.

When the "add" button in the navigation bar of `T` is clicked it will obviously bring up `C` and take in some text from the text field.

Then finally when the send button is pressed I want to add that text from the text field into the `myTableData` array, dismiss `C` (which I plan on doing with `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]`, and update the table view `myTableView` to reflect the changes that I have made.

Does anyone have any idea on how I could accomplish this? Mainly I need help somehow accessing `myTableData` (that lives in `T`) FROM `C`. Then I need to get `T` to recognize that some change has been made and to redraw its cells (probably by instigating cellForRowAtIndexPath). I am aware of how to do this all hardcoded [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html), but I find that method isn't viable if you want to visually represent everything in the storyboard and they do not explain what everything means exactly (like itemInputController for instance).

If my approach is totally incorrect and I don't need all these classes or methods or am doing it all wrong, please feel free to give me a similar approach using the storyboard.

Comment: have experience in custom delegate?

Comment: No, unfortunately I do not

Comment: You can achieve easily with custom delegate. It should be a right time for u to go with the custom delegate because that's one of the important concept.

Comment: Use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12660523/1545180.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `NSMutableArray` and store it in your `NSUserDefaults`. Here's how:

In your `C - UIViewController`, on the `send` button `IBAction` :

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *arr = [defaults objectForKey:@"data"];
[arr addObject:WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD];
[defaults setObject:arr forKey:@"data"];
[defaults synchronise];
```

You can use this same method in T!